# Netbeans and Java Platform Issue

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am dealing with what now appears to be a recurring issue. My Netbeans environment is having an issue with the defined Java Platforms (to be clear, I only have one defined, which of course defaults), and their included libraries for standard java libraries.

Originally, by Java 1.8 platform was using `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162`, and had been for some months now. I started seeing odd behavior this week in my projects where the `java.sql.PrepareStatement` class was throwing the error `cannot find symbol`. I can still see the `.class` file in the projects' libraries, when I expand `Java 1.8 (Default) > rt.jar > java.sql` in the Library tree. However, any imports or usages of the `java.sql.PreparedStatement` class throws errors and doesn't allow the code to compile.

As a quick fix, I installed jdk1.8.0_181, and set it as my new default Java Platform via changing the netbeans`_jdkhome` variable's value in `C:\Program Files\Netbeans 8.0\etc\netbeans.conf`. This got me back up and running, and able to use `PreparedStatement` objects in my projects again both yesterday and this morning. However, I am now getting the same `cannot find symbol` behavior, and the `java.sql.PreparedStatement` class is again no longer properly pulling in, and thus my projects not allowing me to compile or run my code.

EDIT: Just to be clear, this is only affecting the one class. I am able to successfully import other java.* and java.sql.* classes, as per the below screenshot:
[image]

EDIT 2: I did install Netbeans 8.2, and defined jdk1.8.0_181 as the only/default Java Platform. The new version of the IDE is allowing for import/use of the java.sql.PreparedStatement class, while Netbeans 8.0.2 still throws the "cannot find symbol" error. So, I suppose at this point, I can assume something is corrupt/bugged in my 8.0.2 installation. Perhaps I will try to reinstall that version of the IDE, as the new IDE posses issues for maintaining older applications (that require a Source/Binary Format lower than JDK 6).

Comment: NetBeans 8 was released 4 years ago. Why don't you update to 8.2? Just a conjecture, but it seems that you are having some issue with another process... Maybe your anti-virus is messing with your jdk?

Comment: I may try this. Our CIO likes to keep all programmers on the same versions of software, and we usually upgrade in unison. I guess he hasn't seen need for us to upgrade to 8.2, but I may have to be the guinea pig in troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to keep people on the same version of their development platform: JDK, yes, IDE, no (nor should everyone be forced to use a proscribed IDE).

Comment: You are not considering the most likely possibility for _"cannot find symbol"_: some bug(s) in NetBeans. Try [this search](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=%22cannot%20find%20symbol%22) for NetBeans bugs. Also I just just searched for `[netbeans] "cannot find symbol"` on SO and got 155 hits! This is a NetBeans issue that has been around for a very long time, with multiple causes.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall. Just clean NetBeans cache and configurations. If you are using Windows: close NetBeans, delete the folders C:\Users\<Your User>\AppData\Local\NetBeans and C:\Users\<Your User>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans and open the IDE again.

Comment: This is great. Thank you for the advice/insight/tips @davidbuzatto and  skomisa. I will get sure to check the bug reports next time before posting. I will also save these Cache clearing steps for future reference, as I presume that will fix most errors. I am now able to use the jdk1.8.0_181 based Java Platform again in NB 8.0 without the "cannot find symbol" errors. Dave Newton  -- we are a small IT shop (higher ed), so some policies are dated. That being said the CIO doesn't audit this, and would be fine with us using any IDE, as long as our work is done, and done right! hah